# Can a UIView know when it is on screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIView` with a lot of components enclosed in it and would like to update some of them if the view is removed or if its parent view controller is popped/pushed. Is it possible for a `UIView` to get this information

Similar to the method in `UIViewController`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear;
```

Would like something like

```
-(void)UIViewWillAppear;
```

Edit for some comments I saw:

I'll explain a bit more

But I have a special case where the UIView needed to add a "floating view" on top of itself (Imagine a zooming/panning/scrolling UISCrollView subclass with floater on top of itself) such that when it scrolled the floating view stayed in place relative to the superview. I tried recalculating the new origin of the "floater" inside of the `-(void)layoutSubviews` method but the re-placement was very choppy. In order to solve this choppyness problem, the custom UIView added the floating view (which in theory is its subview) as a subview for its superview (a bit of a tongue twister :) ). 
Now arises a problem when the custom UIView is removed (or its containing view controller is pushed offscreen). How can the special UISCrollView remove the floating view from its superView.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `willMoveToSuperview:` to find out when a view is inserted into a hierarchy and when it's removed. That's probably not what you want since the view can be part of a hierarchy and not be inserted by itself.

To find out if it's on screen use `willMoveToWindow:`. If the argument is non-nil the view just became part of a visible view hierarchy.

If you need to do something after the change use `didMoveToWindow:`.

Comment: Looks like it works, but by the time the method is called the view is offscreen.

Answer (score 0):

UIView do not appear/disappear 'randomly' or when they want - your view controllers (or code) control this. So you should find out when you show them, and call code you need.

Comment: I'll add an edit for my comment which appears to be long for this box

Comment: No, the question is valid. The OP wants to build a view that handles its private resources. What you propose would break encapsulation.

Comment: After updating the question - yes, it is valid. However, I think that it anyway should be solved by detecting when main view goes offscreen via controller or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The [**UIView class reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) has some kvo observing change.

By implementing  `-(void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview` you could see the other way round.

**UPDATE After reading the explanations:**

I hope I understood correctly. I did something similiar time ago, but with a UITableView rather than a UIScrollView (but they are quite the same underneath).

It was like a popup detail view. I solved, as you already did, by adding the detail view to the UITableView superview, and then I added a close UIButton in the detail view, with a corresponding IBOutlet:

```
@interface CustomUIView : UIView

@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButtonView *closingButton;

-(void)closeDetail:(IBAction)action;

@end
```

and the action was just:

```
-(void)closeDetail:(IBAction)action {
   // do your cleaning/change to the detail subviews
   [self removeFromSuperview]; // <-- clsoe the detail view
}
```

sdsds